# Pyspark term document matrix -> term in line and document in column for term clustering

Tags: pyspark, k-means, tf-idf

I am a last year french student and I am new at pyspark... I have a problem with the term-document matrix (I worked 3 days in this but without result...)
I have lot of sentence (more than 4 million) and I did the term-document matrix using pyspark.

```
sentenceData = cleanTextRDDtw.map(lambda x: (x[2],x[0]).toDF(["sentence","id"]) 
tokenizer = Tokenizer().setInputCol("sentence").setOutputCol("words")
wordsData = tokenizer.transform(sentenceData)
hashingTF =HashingTF().setInputCol("words").setOutputCol("rawFeatures").setNumFeatures(20)
featurizedData = hashingTF.transform(wordsData)
idf = IDF().setInputCol("rawFeatures").setOutputCol("features")
idfModel = idf.fit(featurizedData)
rescaledData = idfModel.transform(featurizedData)
```

But with this code I obtain document in line and a column (and only one column). In each line of the column there is a fixed-length feature vectors of the value of the tf-idf. The problem is that: with this structure I can not transform my dataframe to matrix and so I can not do the transpose of the matrix in order to have term in line and document in column...

I tried to construct the tf-idf matrix by my own (using loop) but with 4 million sentence the performance of my code was really really bad!

I want a tf-idf matrix with term representing line in order to clusterize (using kmeans) line and not document...

Do you have any idea in order to obtain this matrix? with good performance?

Thank you for all your response,

Comment: What version of spark are you using?

Comment: I am using spark version 1.6.0 and Python version 2.7.5